# node-sass-middleware is not doing anything

Tags: node.js, sass, node-sass

I'm trying to use `node-sass-middleware` but it is not creating a `.css` of my `.scss` file.

My file structure (simplified) is

```
- node-modules
- public
     |- common
     |     |-sass
     |     |     |-style.scss
     |     |-css
- server.js
```

and the code in `server.js` has

```
var cssLoc =  __dirname + "\\public\\common\\css";
var cssDest =  __dirname + "\\public\\common";
console.log(cssLoc);
console.log(cssDest);
app.use(sass({
    src: cssLoc,
    dest: cssDest,
    debug: true,
    outputStyle: 'compressed'
}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

I have no idea why this isn't working. It is very frustrating.

Answer (score 9):

The very likely reason that it's not working is because confusingly the **node-sass-middleware** will take the path specified on its **src** and **dest** properties and then look at the local **css** file references in your html  tags, grab the paths they reference, and look for those exact paths in the **src** and **dest** paths specified.

Example(in your app.js file):

```
var nodeSassMiddleware = require('node-sass-middleware');

app.use(nodeSassMiddleware({
   src: path.join(__dirname, 'assets'),
   dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
});
```

Then in your base html file contains a link tag like so:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/immediate/style.css"`

**node-sass-middleware** will look for **/assets/immediate/style.scss** and output that file to **/public/immediate/style.css**

It's actually quite nifty once you realize what's going on :), fire up your server in your console and visit the link in the browser and you the console will log the actual source and destination paths being used.

Banged my head against the wall a while figuring this out, hope it helps!

Comment: this should have been the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the original example with the following directory structure:

```
- node-modules
- public
     |- common
     |     |-sass
     |     |     |-style.scss
     |     |-css
- server.js
```

In `server.js` where you are calling the `node-sass-middleware` it looks like you have the `src` and `dest` properties set incorrectly. For example,

```
var cssLoc =  __dirname + "\\public\\common\\css";
```

which is being used to populate the `src` property should be the path to your *.scss file but instead is pointing to your CSS destination directory. Similarly, the `dest` property,

```
var cssDest =  __dirname + "\\public\\common";
```

is not pointing to the CSS directory but its parent.

In the `sass-node-middleware` block you have `debug: true` set so you should be able to view the paths used in your console from where your launched the application to verify whether they are correct or not:

```
app.use(sass({
    src: cssLoc,
    dest: cssDest,
    debug: true,
    outputStyle: 'compressed'
}));
```

This could be refactored to:

```
app.use(sass({
    src: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'common', 'sass'),
    dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'common', 'css'),
    debug: true,
    outputStyle: 'compressed'
}));
```

That should get your SASS compiled into CSS but as the previous answer by SirRodge mentioned you still have your path to resolve for the the `get` request of the CSS. If you are using the express.static built-in middleware, `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` to serve files from a directory named `public` and in your HTML you are referencing the CSS by say `/common/css/style.css` then you need to add the `prefix` property to the middleware:

```
app.use(sass({
    src: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'common', 'sass'),
    dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'common', 'css'),
    debug: true,
    outputStyle: 'compressed',
    prefix: '/common/css'
}));
```